# Cannot find the 'move database server' button in the new Windows Azure management portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I just switched to the new management portal of Windows Azure (and I really like it), but when I tried to move my database server from one subscription to another (see this link for how it is done in the old portal: [Moving SQL Azure Servers Between Subscriptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/03/07/moving-sql-azure-servers-between-subscriptions.aspx)), I could not find the button to move my server. Am I not looking in the right place or is this functionalitiy not available in the preview portal?

B.t.w. I was able to move my server by using the old portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of features missing from the new portal (i.e. SQL Reporting, Access Control Service, Traffic Manager, Service Bus, Management Certificates).

I guess these will be added in over time. For the time being, you can still access the old portal by clicking on the green box at the top the new portal, or going here: https://windows.azure.com/default.aspx

Comment: The new portal is a "preview", aka its not yet feature complete. Over the coming weeks and months I expect we'll see if fleshed out a bit more before eventually becoming the only option.

Answer (score 0):

If any functionality no available in new portal and was in old portal, just keep accessing old portal at:

- OLD Portal: https://windows.azure.com/
- NEW Portal: https://manage.windowsazure.com/

Answer (score 0):

Old portal is now retired and still some, if not a lot of functionality is not there.  Cannot move a server or a DB to a different subscription by one-self.